# How do I get selected cells of a table to wrap the content and keep their width?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[image: existing table]

I'm using tailwind, but that shouldn't matter. I need the columns with predictable content to be a specific width only, unchanging. Description, Client and Customer need a min and max width, and then wrap the content at max.

For example, the Description column above is tailwindcss "w-10" which is basically the same as css `td.desc {width: 40px;}`. As you can see, it has completely ignored any width declaration.

Can I achieve this per-cell width control with tables, or am I going to need to punt out to css grid?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. You don't want to use css? Need something like `<table><tr><td width="200"></td></tr></table>`?

Comment: @AndreiFedorov added some clarification.

Comment: Just a framework, this can be important. Perhaps inside it there is a class meaning adaptive width or vice versa fixed width. Unfortunately, I do not own this framework.

Comment: If you share your markup there is a much greater chance of someone being able to help you.